# What is the difference between "می‌گفت" and "میگفت"?

Tags: alphabets, persian

I read in WP's entry on [Persian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet) that the "ye" final form is 'ﯽ', and its medial form is 'ﯿ'.

Logically, when typing "می‌گفت", most software automagically write "میگفت".

However, [the wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DA%AF%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86), as well as first google results for "میگفت", use the "می‌گفت" form.

What is the difference between "می‌گفت" and "میگفت", if any ?  And why is the final form used in the middle of this word (there is no space after) instead of the medial form for this particular word ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. It is just a matter of spelling. You can write the particle مى as a separate word, or you can join it to the following verb.

Comment: +1, 
some scholars suggest "می‌گفت" is the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

`می` is the shortened form of `همی` which used to be spelled separately in old Persian, therefore `می‌گفت` is usually considered more correct by scholars.

Comment: I think you don't mean "Old Persian". You mean "Early New Persian".